# To Select latest data per group from joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to select data from two tables and the query is below.

```
SELECT
   accounts.firstname, accounts.mobileno, accounts.address, todotasks.lastmodified
FROM accounts
JOIN todotasks ON accounts.imeino = todotasks.assignedto
WHERE status = 'Completed'
```

Now I want the latest modified time to be displayed from the table.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Then dont use the `LIMIT`

Comment: Ohk.. Got it.. Updating.

Comment: An example would have made it much easier to understand

Comment: Correct answer downvoted incorrect accepted???

Comment: i want the check the condition where status is completed till today date

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just `group` your data and pick latest date with `MAX` function like this:

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.mobileno, a.address, MAX(t.lastmodified) AS lastmodified
FROM accounts a
JOIN todotasks t ON a.imeino = t.assignedto
WHERE status = 'Completed'
GROUP BY a.firstname, a.mobileno, a.address
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.mobileno, a.address, MAX(t1.lastmodified) AS lastmodified
FROM accounts a
JOIN todotasks t1 ON a.imeino = t1.assignedto
WHERE status = 'Completed' AND 
      NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM todotasks t2 WHERE t2.assignedto = t1.assignedto AND
                                                  t2.status <> 'Completed' AND
                                                  t2.lastmodified > t1.lastmodified 
                                                --AND t2.TaskNo = t1.TaskNo)
GROUP BY a.firstname, a.mobileno, a.address
```

Comment: @User, it is unclear. Didn't the answer satisfied your question? Can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @User, do you want to check if the latest record has Completed status?

Comment: @User, can you here me? It is not clear what does `is completed till today` mean. Can you edit your question with some sample data that explains what you need?

Comment: @User instead of `MAX(t.lastmodified)` select desired date i.e. `NOW()`. This will display `08/06`

Comment: @User, `because in some cases a new process will be started again ` this is what I wanted. It is an important information. Ok I will let you know when I will finish

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY todotasks.lastmodified DESC` -

```
SELECT
   accounts.firstname, accounts.mobileno, accounts.address, todotasks.lastmodified
FROM accounts
JOIN todotasks ON accounts.imeino = todotasks.assignedto
WHERE status = 'Completed'
AND todotasks.lastmodified = (SELECT lastmodified FROM todotasks ORDER BY lastmodified DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you just want to group per account. Given your full table schema isn't available to us, the following is a best guess:

```
SELECT
   accounts.firstname, accounts.mobileno, accounts.address, max(todotasks.lastmodified)
FROM accounts
JOIN todotasks ON accounts.imeino = todotasks.assignedto
WHERE status = 'Completed'
GROUP BY accounts.imeino
```

The assumption here is that `imeino` is unique per account, and that `firstname`, `mobileno` and `address` do not change for each unique imeino.